# Solidity inheritance and VM Exception

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I'm building a dapp using Solidity and Truffle. But when testing, I get the following error when I try to execute `createPost` (using js tests):

`Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

Please look at the following codes.

**campaign** contract:

```
contract Campaign {
  uint256 currentIndex;
 
  struct CampaignStruct {
    uint256 id;
    address user;
    string title;
    bool isExist;
  }
  struct CampaignInputStruct {
    string title;
  }
  CampaignStruct[] private campaigns;

  // ...

  constructor() {
    currentIndex = campaigns.length;
  }

  /// @notice Check if campaign exists
  function isCampaignExists(uint256 index) public view returns (bool) {
    if (campaigns[index].isExist) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function createCampaign(
    CampaignInputStruct memory _input,
  ) public returns (bool) {
    // Code for create a campaign
    // ...
    currentIndex++;
    return true;
  }
}
```

**Post** contract:

```
import "./Campaign.sol";

contract Post is Campaign {
  uint256 currentPostIndex;

  struct PostStruct {
    uint256 id;
    address user;
    string title;
    string body;
    uint256 campaignId; // THIS IS IMPORTANT
  }
  struct PostInputStruct {
    string title;
    string body;
    uint256 campaignId;
  }

  PostStruct[] private posts;

  modifier onlyValidPostInput(PostInputStruct memory _input) {
    /// ... 
    uint256 campaignId = uint256(_input.campaignId);
    bool isExist = isCampaignExists(campaignId); /// I THINK THE PROBLEM IS HERE
    if(VALIDATION){
      /// INVALID DATA
    }
    _;
  }

  constructor() {
    currentPostIndex = posts.length;
  }

  function createPost(PostInputStruct memory _input)
    external
    onlyValidPostInput(_input)
    returns (bool)
  {
    // Codes for create a post
    currentPostIndex++;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Why need to call `isCampaignExists` before `createPost`?
Because I need to know if `campaignId` is valid or not.

Problem:
Apparently, the problem is with `isCampaignExists`. The strange thing is that this function works well in `Campaign` contract tests.

Answer (score 0):

Parent contracts can either be called directly or by using the *super* keyword.

Note that once keyword *super* is used, all of the immediate parent contracts are called.

Refer to the following example:

```
contract A {
    event Log(string message);

    function foo() public virtual {
        emit Log("A.foo called");
    }

    function bar() public virtual {
        emit Log("A.bar called");
    }
}
    
contract B is A {
    function foo() public virtual override {
        emit Log("B.foo called");
        A.foo();
    }

    function bar() public virtual override {
        emit Log("B.bar called");
        super.bar();
    }
}
```

Example taken from https://solidity-by-example.org/super/.

So, the following should eliminate your inheritance problem: `bool isExist = Campaign.isCampaignExists(campaignId);`

Comment: I used this method. I get the same error again.